# How to override groups permission over users permission in SenseNet?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sensenet

I am using SenseNet V 6.3 Community Edition.

I am doing these steps:

1. I have set Allow permission of node `p` to user `xyz@xyz.com`
2. Access node `p` from user `xyz@xyz.com` by `Node.LoadNode()` (Successful)
3. I have set deny permission of node `p` to user `xyz@xyz.com`
4. I have set allow permission of node `p` to group which have `xyz@xyz.com` as member
5. Access node `p` from user `xyz@xyz.com` by `Node.LoadNode()` (Error)

I am getting `Access Denied` error.

It seems not overriding groups permission over users permission or it seems not overriding latest permission.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design: *deny* permission is always stronger than *allow*. So if you set explicit deny for a user, you cannot allow the same thing through a group. The time of setting the permissions or whether it is a group or user does not matter: the rule is that deny overrides allow.

This is why working with *deny* should be the last option. It is better to *remove* the allow permission for a user and than you can allow it through a group.

For details about *breaking* permissions, *local* permissions and the whole permission system in general, please visit [this article](https://community.sensenet.com/docs/permission-system/).

Comment: how can I remove allow permission of specific user for specific node c# api ?

Comment: Hi @miklos , I got how to remove allow permission instead of deny permission, Thanks for your response